# JavaScript: how do I generalize this function that checks to see if two arrays has intersection?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function `isIntersected` that can check if two arrays have an intersection.

```js
function isIntersected(arrayA, arrayB) {
    return arrayA.some(itemA => arrayB.some(itemB => itemA === itemB))
}

 
const arr1 = ['pizza', 'cake', 'cola'];
const arr2 = ['pizza', 'beer'];

isIntersected(arr1, arr2) // true
```

The issue now I have is that I'd like to generalize this to support an indefinite number of arrays so that if all of the arrays share members it returns `true`, otherwise `false`, for example:

```js
const arr1 = ['pizza', 'cake', 'cola'];
const arr2 = ['pizza', 'beer'];
const arr3 = ['pizza', 'banana'];
const arr4 = ['pizza', 'apple'];

isIntersected(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4) // true
```

I don't know how I should tweak my existing function to support this change.

Comment: What do you want to return? If all of the arrays have an intersection with each other? If any of them have an intersection? If there's a value that can be found in all of the arrays?

Comment: should it return true if *any* of those arrays share members, or *all* of the arrays share members? It could get exponentially more complex as your inputs grow...

Comment: What should the result be for `isIntersected(['pizza', 'cake'], ['pizza'], ['cake'])`? There is intersection between first and any other but not between the last two. What about `isIntersected(['pizza', 'cake'], ['pizza', 'beer'], ['cake', 'beer'])` - there is intersection between each but they don't overlap.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be looking for

```
function isIntersected(first, ...rest) {
    return first.some(item => rest.every(arr => arr.includes(item)))
}
```